# Как преобразовать excel в json

Tags: python, json, excel

Есть файл excel, в котором названия столбцов и сами данные могут быть как на русском, так и на английском языке, но при конвертации его в json слетает кодировка для строк на русском языке
Пример слова Наименование

```
\u043d\u0430\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435"
```

Помогите пожалуйста преобразовать данные с сохранением языка.

Использую pandas

```
import pandas
excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('name.xlsx', sheet_name='Ex')
json_str = excel_data_df.to_json(orient='records')
print(json_str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте кодировку UTF-8, тогда проблем с русским не должно быть:

```
import pandas

excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('name.xlsx', sheet_name='Ex')
json_str = excel_data_df.to_json(orient='records', force_ascii=False)
print(json_str)
```

Comment: для python3.10 encoding был удален из аргументов к to_json

Comment: Тогда вместо encoding='utf-8', можно попробовать использовать force_ascii=False